# Add new row every set number of children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a new row every 2 childrens and place 2 new childrens inside a new row each time.

The starting html:

```
<div class="row_1"></div>
```

After the first run i get:

```
<div class="newRow">
   <div class="span6" id="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="row_1"></div>
```

But as I keep adding I get:

```
<div class="newRow">
  <div class="span6">...</div>
  <div class="span6" id="content">...</div>
  <div class="span6" id="content"></div> <== Empty extra div
</div>
<div class="newRow"></div> <== Empty extra div
<div class="row_1"></div>
```

Expected result would be

```
<div class="newRow">
  <div class="span6">...</div>
  <div class="span6" id="content">...</div>
</div>
<div class="newRow">
  <div class="span6">...</div>
  <div class="span6">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row_1"></div>
```

The following is the jQuery I am using

```
$(".nav li a").on("click", function(e) {

$('#content').removeAttr('id');

var $row = $(".row_1");
var $rowNew = $('.newRow');

if($rowNew.length < 2){
        $('<div id="content" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.newRow');
} 

if ($rowNew.children().length > 2) {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertBefore($row);
}

else {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertBefore($row);
        $('<div id="content" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.newRow');
}
});
```

Comment: So, what exactly do you expect the output to be? Can you post an example?

Comment: I've edited my question and I have now included the expected result, thanks

Comment: Does this really need to a complex JS solution? Can this be a bunch of `float:left` divs with width limitation on the parent to match two divs?

Comment: I am using ajax to load new divs and to add them I need to run jQuery, they are not automatically populated

Comment: It's obvious by looking at your if statements what is happening. Both the first if, and the else of the second are running. Did you intend for the second if to be an elseif?

Comment: Then it would really help if you could post what your ajax call returns.

Comment: I don't see when the first `.newRow` is added. Your first run is different from my first run. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/WMPpz/

Comment: @Simon I did write the html result, which is the ajax output

Comment: You posted the expected result, but there's nothing about ajax there. Also, your question title and description are very misleading.

Comment: @Blazemonger That is adding new rows, but I need to add a new row if there isn't but once there is, I need to add 2 content div inside it then create a new row and so on..Check "expected result" in my question

Comment: @rob.m it doesn't matter where do you get the content. I am talking about "row" management. It can be based on CSS rules like this http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/UJPHR/1/

Comment: @llia G I see what you mean but how would you place new 2 childrens always in the first row? In your example the third child goes below the first 2 and so on

Comment: @rob.m If that is not what you wanted, then I don't really understand what you mean...

Comment: @llia G I need to add 2 childrens for each row and have the new added childrens always at the top of the row and I need to use jQuery for it

Comment: @rob.m so just change `appendTo()` to `prependTo()`? I don't really udnerstand what you mean by "have the new added childrens always at the top of the row". Rows are usually horizontal. You mean at the top of the column?

Comment: To be honest I have been fairly clear here. 34 own answers on 60 questions isn't bad, I answered the questions myself? Better no? The "evenually.." Has nothing to do with expressing mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Eventually I solved it with":

```
$(".nav li a").on("click", function(e) {

$('#content').removeAttr('id');

var $row = $(".span9");
var $rowNew = $('.new');

if ($rowNew.children().length > 1) {
        $(".span9 div").removeClass("new");
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').prependTo($row);
}

if ($(".new").length == 0) {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').prependTo($row);
        $('<div id="content" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');
} else {
    $('<div id="content" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');
}

});
```